# How can i unify 2 images with drag and drop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drag-and-drop

i have 2 css classes , left side and right side of screen and i need to put them togheter, in these classes i have images which look like a puzzle: [image]

By dragging image from the right side to the left side.At drop,must fit with the image from left side. I read about drag and drop but didnt find something like that :(
What i've tried?

EDIT: http://postimg.org/image/je31ptb6d/ (this is an example with my pictures.On top are images separated as classes - class="left" for ca and class="right" for nă.On bottom are images after i drop the image from right to one from left.My question is how to specify the correct drop zone to make images look like bottom one from link after i drop image from right side? )

JS/Jquery:

```
// shuffle function for right side only

$(document).ready(function() {
var a = $(".right > img").remove().toArray();
for (var i = a.length - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
    var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    var bi = a[i];
    var bj = a[j];
    a[i] = bj;
    a[j] = bi;
}
$(".right").append(a);
    });

// drag and drop

$(function() {
    $( ".right img" ).draggable
    ({
        cursor: 'move',
        revert: 'invalid',
    });
    $( ".left img" ).droppable({
        tolerance: 'fit', 
    });
  });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="left">
<img class="piese" id="piesa1" src="images/Text_1.svg" />
<img class="piese" id="piesa2" src="images/Text_2.svg" />
<img class="piese" id="piesa3" src="images/Text_3.svg" />
<img class="piese" id="piesa4" src="images/Text_4.svg" />
</div>

<div class="right">
<img class="piese" id="piesa5" src="images/Text_5.svg" />
<img class="piese" id="piesa6" src="images/Text_6.svg" />
<img class="piese" id="piesa7" src="images/Text_7.svg" />
<img class="piese" id="piesa8" src="images/Text_8.svg" />
</div>
```

Comment: "fit" means it is the same SIZE the target element. This has nothing to do with the shape of what's in the image. Drag-drop doesn't do a geometrical analysis of images.

Comment: Have another element which is a wrapper around each `<img>` and the drag/drops on that element. Then, when you get a matching side with a drop, move all the elements from one wrapper into the other, and destroy the empty wrapper. Now when the remaining wrapper is moved, all of the pieces that were joined together move too because they're inside it

Comment: @Diodeus when i said "fit" i ment to make from 2 images another one with diferent length...something like image 1 + image 2.But my problem is that right side of left image is not straight its meandering and dunno how to set drop zone in its right side to drop the image

Comment: Make a wrapper that is the same size.

Comment: Has anyone any ideea of how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve your problem you must build a grid
and use drag drop by taking as a reference the location of the squares of the grid.
This is a simple example to give you an idea.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Example</title>
<style>
#grid{
    background-color: #09F; 
    height: 130px;
    width: 390px;
    position:relative;
    margin:100px auto;
}
.square{
    height: 128px;
    width: 128px;
    border:1px solid #999;
    float:left;
}
#first-image{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
}
#second-image{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<!--take two images by 120px with this class and id -->
<div id="grid">
    <img class="dr" id="first-image" src="your-image.png" width="128" height="128">
    <img class="dr" id="second-image" src="your-image.png" width="128" height="128">
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
        for(xx = 0; xx < 3; xx++) {
          $("#grid").append($('<div class="square"></div>'));
        };
        $('.dr').on("dragstart", function (event) {
          var dt = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
          dt.setData('Text', $(this).attr('id'));
        });
        $('div.square').on("dragenter dragover drop", function (event) {    
           event.preventDefault();
           if (event.type === 'drop') {
              var data = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('Text',$(this).attr('id'));
              de=$('#'+data).detach();
              var x = $(this).position().left;
              var y = $(this).position().top;
              de.css({'position':'absolute','top':y+'px','left':x+'px'}).appendTo($(this)); 
           };
       });
   });  
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: nice example,im gonna try it for my project.Thanks